# Accessing first element of a tuple in a list of tuples, in a list - python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Im fairly new to python, and I have a list of two lists, with 5 tuples each, called 'cos':

```
cos =  ([('B6409', 0.9997), ('S4193', 0.9996), ('C9826', 0.9995), ('J6706', 0.9994), ('Q0781', 0.9993)] , [('A5474', 0.9985), ('H1286', 0.9981), ('Y1178', 0.998), ('D2742', 0.9979), ('A7668', 0.9979)])
```

Id like to iterate over this list and match the first element of each tuple, ie: 'B6409' and 'S4193' with the keys of a dictionary called 'dist', ie: 'R7033' , 'B6409' etc...

```
dist = { 'R7033': [93.9636, 32.6327, 33.092]  ,   'V3259': [84.8378, 27.3658, 29.1537]  ,  'B6409': [55.6789, 67.5673, 89.7856] }
```

So effectively an if statement saying 'if the first element of each tuple in each list(two of them) is equal to a key in the dictionary 'dict', perform a calculation to sum up the values of that key.
So for example since the first element of one of the tuples in the list 'cos' is 'B6409', and it IS one of they keys in dictionary 'dict', sum up the list of values of key 'B6409'.

Im just getting confused on the indexing of elements within the list of list with tuples and so far i have done only know to use

```
for i in dist.keys():
 for j in cos....
     if i == cos[?][?][?]:
         sum1 = sum(dist[i])
```

how is a way i can do this iteration loop?
thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output for your posted example inputs?

Comment: `for j in cos` will mean `j` is one of your lists of tuples (i.e. `cos[0]` or `cos[1]`), you can get the first tuple with `j[0]` and the first element of the first tuple with `j[0][0]`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your intention correctly, then you could use a comprehension to generate a list of keys from `cos` and then another comprehension to generate a dictionary whose values are the corresponding sums:

```
cos =  ([('B6409', 0.9997), ('S4193', 0.9996), ('C9826', 0.9995), ('J6706', 0.9994), ('Q0781', 0.9993)] , [('A5474', 0.9985), ('H1286', 0.9981), ('Y1178', 0.998), ('D2742', 0.9979), ('A7668', 0.9979)])
dist = { 'R7033': [93.9636, 32.6327, 33.092]  ,   'V3259': [84.8378, 27.3658, 29.1537]  ,  'B6409': [55.6789, 67.5673, 89.7856] }

keys = [item[0][0] for item in cos]
key_to_sum_dict = {key: sum(dist[key]) for key in keys if key in dist}
```

Which gives `{'B6409': 213.0318}`.

Comment: Yep, that works great I think. Now i just need to do this for both lists.

Comment: BTW, it also seems like `cos` is not structured in a consistent way. I figured it was a typo, but still...

Answer (score 0):

A way to iterate over `cos` would be:

```
for dist_key in dist.keys():
  for cos_list in cos:
    for cos_tuple in cos_list:
      if dist_key == cos_tuple[0]:
        sum1 = sum(dist[dist_key])
```